# Is it possible to create a custom paginator in laravel 5 with previous and next buttons?

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

I want to create a custom laravel 5 paginator which does not take the count of the collection for pagination and has next and previous links possibly. So the data is loaded sooner like when LIMIT is used. The count of the collection delays the process, so I want a paginator that displays first 15 or 20 results and next as the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Please add how you use the pagination currently and what do expect the end result to be.

Comment: "If you only need to display simple "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you have the option of using the simplePaginate method to perform a more efficient query. This is very useful for large datasets if you do not need to display a link for each page number when rendering your view" https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination